# How to specify ppd when adding CUPS printer

Tags: linux, cups

On client's Oracle 7 server, I have added printers to cups using the cli. I use this command line for adding:

```
lpadmin -p Warehouse3Printer -v smb://printer:printer@172.16.192.2/HPLaser -P ./Downloads/HP-LaserJet_P2014n.ppd
```

Client has many printers and nearly all are different models. They are attached to Windows PC's via USB and shared as "HPLaser". Each PC has a local user named "printer".

Various RPM's, such as foomatic, place files in /usr/share/cups such as: /usr/share/cups/model/HP-LaserJet_Pro_CP1025nw.ppd.gz.

What I do atm, if the ppd is not on the system, I download it from the Net into my home directory first and use that, else I copy it from /usr/share/cups.

Firstly, what is the correct syntax for selecting a file already in /usr/share/cups? Is the one I am using correct, or should it be different?

Secondly, I see that many of the files are gzipped. Can they be selected as is or do I need to gunzip them first?